# How to find the conditional distribution of $X$, given $Y=10$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

The question is :

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are jointly normal random variables such that $E(Y)=2$, $Var(Y)=9$, $E(X)=5$ ,$Var(X)=16$ and $Cov(X,Y)=1/2$. What is the conditional distribution of $X$ given $Y=10$?

I know that the conditional distribution of $X$ given $Y$ is normal with mean $E[X|Y]$ and variance is $(1-\rho)^2 \sigma_X^2$,

where $\rho = \frac{E(XY)}{\sigma_X \sigma_Y}$ and $E[X|Y]= E(X)+ \rho \frac{\sigma_X}{\sigma_Y}(Y-E(Y))$.

In my calculation, I am little confuse with the computation of the term $E(XY)$?

There is also a hint given in the book to solve this problem. Represent $X = a + bY+ cZ$ where $Z$ is a $N(0,1)$ random variable independent of $Y$. Can anyone give me a thought how I can solve this question with the given hint?

Comment: $\mathbb E(XY)=Cov(X,Y)+\mathbb E(X)\cdot \mathbb E(Y)$. The hint doesn't ring a bell.

Comment: You can get proper formatting for operators like $\operatorname{Var}$ using `\operatorname{Var}`.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More generally, let $X\sim N(\mu_X,\sigma^2_X),Y\sim N(\mu_Y,\sigma^2_Y),\text{Cov}(X,Y)=\sigma_{XY},\text{Corr}(X,Y)=\rho.$

If you already know the formulas for the conditional distribution, then you should be able to compute $E[XY]=\sigma_{XY}+\mu_X\mu_Y$ and finish the problem.

---

As for the hint, it essentially gives you a way to derive the formulas from scratch. To see why, note that a sum of independent normals is normal, so with appropriately chosen $a,b,c$ and $Y\mathrel{\unicode{x2AEB}} \quad Z\sim N(0,1)$, we can write

$$X=a+bY+cZ.$$

We have three conditions to meet that determine $a,b,c$:

$$\mu_X=E[a+bY+cZ]=a+b\mu_Y\\
\sigma_X^2=V(a+bY+cZ)=b^2\sigma^2_Y+c^2\\
\sigma_{XY}=\text{Cov}(a+bY+cZ,Y)=b\sigma^2_Y,$$

which imply

$$b=\sigma_{XY}/\sigma^2_Y=\rho \frac{\sigma_X}{\sigma_Y}\\
c^2=(1-\rho^2)\sigma^2_X \\
a=\mu_X-\rho \frac{\sigma_X}{\sigma_Y}\mu_Y.$$

By independence, $Z|Y=_d Z$ so $Z|Y$ is normal, implying $X|Y$ is normal with

$$E[X|Y]=a+bY+cE[Z|Y]=a+bY+cE[Z]=a+bY\\
Var(X|Y)=c^2V(Z|Y)=c^2V(Z)=c^2.$$

---

Note: In the above, we took it as given that $Z,Y$ are independent as per the hint. However, since $Z$ was defined based on $X,Y$, this must technically be proven. We can do so by showing $(Z,Y)'$ are jointly normal (hint: we can write this is as an affine transform of $(X,Y)'$) and observe that our choice of $a,b,c$ imply $Z,Y$ are uncorrelated. Uncorrelated and jointly normal implies independent.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand the other way to solve this one.

Comment: No prob. It's not really two different ways to solve it. Rather the hint in your book just tells you how to derive the formulas